# NullPointerException from Catalina when starting Tomcat with JMS Tibco EMS JNDI resources

Tags: tomcat, jms, jndi, atmosphere, tibco-ems

in my Primefaces application I want to use atmosphere framework 's `JMSBroadcaster` in order to propagate messages between 2 instances of my application.

To do that, I need to lookup (JNDI) for JMS `ConnectionFactory` and `Topic` (the implementation we are using is Tibco EMS).

I am very new to JMS and I cannot figure how to configure a Tibco JMS resource in Tomcat's `context.xml` and `server.xml` (I am not using active MQ). I am trying to declare these JMS resources from EMS in Tomcat 8.
I added `tibjms-7.0.1.jar` and `jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar` in `tomcat8/lib/`

But, at tomcat startup, I get the following error (even without any war deployed) :

> SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans RuntimeException java.lang.NullPointerException

I cannot figure out how where is the problem (I am not sure I can have more details about this logged error).

Here is my tomcat configuration :

In `server.xml`

```
<Resource 
    id="atmosphereFactory" 
    name="jms/atmosphereFactory"   
    jndiName="atmosphereFactory"  
    auth="Container"  
    type="com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory"  
    factory="com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsObjectFactory"  
    factoryClass="com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory"  
    brokerName="localhost"  
    brokerURL="tcp://localhost:7222"  
    serverUrl="localhost:7222"  
    userName="admin"  
    password="" />
<Resource 
    id="atmosphere" 
    name="jms/atmosphere/test.atmo"
    jndiName="atmosphere"
    auth="Container"
    type="com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsTopic" 
    factory="com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsObjectFactory"
    physicalName="test.atmo"/>
```

In `context.xml`

```
<ResourceLink 
    global="jms/atmosphereFactory" 
    name="jms/atmosphereFactory" 
    type="com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory" />
<ResourceLink 
    global="jms/atmosphere" 
    name="jms/atmosphere" 
    type="com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsTopic" />
```

Alternatively, I might also be interested in a way to configure atmosphere's `JMSBroadcaster` using `ConnectionFactory` and `Topic` injected from Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually used Spring to instanciate Jms Topic...

```
<!-- Connection to Tibco EMS -->
<bean id="tibjmsConnectionFactory" class="com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory">
    <property name="serverUrl" value="${instance.jms.server}" />
    <property name="userName" value="${instance.jms.login}"/>
    <property name="userPassword" value="${instance.jms.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplateEms" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="tibjmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="explicitQosEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="deliveryMode" value="2" />
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="false" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="${instance.wait.timeout}" />
</bean>

<bean id="pushJmsMessageListener" class="com.agipi.g2a.tiana.web.utils.PushJmsMessageListener" />

<bean id="atmosphereTopic" class="com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsTopic">
    <!-- nom du topic-->
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${instance.jms.atmosphere.topic.name}" />
</bean>
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="tibjmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="atmosphereTopic"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="pushJmsMessageListener" />
</bean>
```

... and created a MessageListener which listen to atmosphere topic and publish received message to Push event bus ...

```
class PushJmsMessageListener implements MessageListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PushJmsMessageListener.class);

    private static final String PROPERTY_PUSH_CHANNEL = "pushChannel";

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        try {
            EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
            TextMessage testMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            LOGGER.info("Reception d'un message du topic atmosphere : {}", testMessage);

            String canal = testMessage.getStringProperty(PROPERTY_PUSH_CHANNEL);
            Object decodedObject = new JSONDecoder().decode(testMessage.getText());
            LOGGER.info("Envoi du message sur le endpoint push [canal={},objet={}]", canal, decodedObject);
            eventBus.publish(canal, decodedObject);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            LOGGER.error("error.receiving.jms.message", e);

        }
    }
}
```

... and created a Spring service to publish my message to the topic instead of push ...

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "singleton")
public class JmsAtmosphereServiceImpl implements JmsAtmosphereService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jmsTemplateEms")
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("atmosphereTopic")
    private Topic atmosphereTopic;


    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String pushChannel, String jsonContent) {
        jmsTemplate.send(atmosphereTopic, session -> {
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(jsonContent);
            textMessage.setStringProperty("pushChannel", pushChannel);
            return textMessage;
        });

    }

}
```

... some utility to abstract ...

```
@Service
public class PushJmsUtils {

    private static final String PUSH_DEFAULT_CHANNEL = "atmosphere";

    @Autowired
    private JmsAtmosphereService jmsAtmosphereService;

    /**
     * Propagate message JMS as JSON to JMS Atmosphere topic.
     *
     * @param channel push channel
     * @param message object to send via push
     */
    public void propagateMessage(String channel, Object message) {
        String id = channel;
        if (id.startsWith("/*")) {
            id = PUSH_DEFAULT_CHANNEL;
        }
        jmsAtmosphereService.sendMessage(id, new JSONEncoder().encode(message));
    }

}
```

.. and then, I publish my message to several instances of my application listening to the same atmosphere topic (including the application sending the message).

```
 pushJmsUtils.propagateMessage(canal,pushMessage);
```